# How to navigate to .ts files

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-console

I want to debug my Angular Typescript code, but when I open `sources` in my chrome console I only see these files:

[image: the files]

They all weird code in them that I don't recognise.According to [this question's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714537/chrome-debug-angular-typescript-how-to-navigate-to-ts-file), I should see the `.ts` files in my `webpack` folder. But there is no webpack folder. Where is my code? ^^

The website is deployed on cloud foundry.

Comment: If it's a deployed production build then there's not much you can do, you're not supposed to debug it in the first place

Comment: Ah ok, good that I didn't know, thanks for the hint ; )

Comment: If you're on your local, if you disable bundling and turn off prod mode, then it will be in the expected folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your TypeScript code should be in the `main-[EcmaScript version].[some numbers & letters].js` file. Your code will be minified and consolidated, so it will be very difficult to debug as it is. There is an option in Chrome to 'pretty print' a file, which will do a good job making the code more readable.